# Sending JSON object to my Ajax method in a controlelr

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I am trying to call a method in my controller using ajax and passing an object. I can do this very well when it comes to variables but can't seem to do it using an object. The method is called fine, but the object values are always null. I have also tried using .toJSON method but get this error Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new d.fn.init(a,b,g)} has no method 'toJSON' , yes, I have JSON2 included

Here is my attempt so far:

```
var VoucherDetails = this.GetVoucherDetails();

    $.post("/Vouchers/GetVoucherPreviewTemplate", { "Voucher": VoucherDetails},
            function (data) {


            });


  function GetVoucherDetails()
    {
        var teet = $("#Title").val();      


        return { Title: teet };
    }


C#

  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetVoucherPreviewTemplate(ENT_Voucher Voucher)
        {
            return Json("");
        }
```

Here is my ENT_Voucher code:

```
[Serializable]
    public class ENT_Voucher : ENT_VoucherEntityBase
    {   
        public int BusinessID { get; set; }
        public int? SiteID { get; set; }  
        public string Title { get; set; }    
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }   
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
        public string ImageLink { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public ENT_Business BusinessDetails { get; set; }
        public string VoucherTandC { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public string DaysRemaining { get; set; }
        public int RequestCount { get; set; }
        public bool IsPetoba { get; set; }

        public ENT_Voucher()
        {
            this.BusinessDetails = new ENT_Business();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also show ENT_Voucher C# class? So far your present code looks OK.

Answer (score 2):

You could send it as a JSON request which allows you to send arbitrarily complex objects:

```
var VoucherDetails = this.GetVoucherDetails();
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetVoucherPreviewTemplate", "Vouchers")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ voucher: VoucherDetails }),
    success: function(result) {

    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have JSON2.js included then you want to use JSON.stringify() and pass it the data to serialize in your AJAX call!